# Java: Overriding Method in Derrived Class with Different Return Type?

Tags: java, programming-languages, overloading

In the following java code, NetBeans complains with or without the @Override statement. 
If the Override is not present I get an error that the return types `Pair<Interval, Interval>` and `Pair<ExtendedInterval, ExtendedInterval>` are not compatible. The interpreter suggests that I add an @Override statement.  However, the same error occurs with the @Override statement.

What's the best way to make this error go away?  I would prefer that the caller not have to cast the returned objects to the correct class.

```
public class Interval {
    private Date left;
    private Date right;

    public Pair<Interval, Interval> split(Date dt){
        ...
        return new Pair<Interval, Interval>(
                        new Interval(left, dt),
                        new Interval(dt, right));
    }
}

public class ExtendedInterval extends Interval {
    private Data localData;

    @Override
    public Pair<ExtendedInterval, ExtendedInterval> split(Date dt){
        Pair<Interval, Interval> baseInterval = super.split(dt);
        return new Pair<ExtendedInterval, ExtendedInterval>(
                              new ExtendedInterval(localData, baseInterval.first()),
                              new ExtendedInterval(localData, baseInterval.second()));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could change the base class method to:

```
public Pair<? extends Interval, ? extends Interval> split(Date dt)
```

I believe that would work.

The problem is that without that, it simply isn't type safe. Suppose `Pair` has a `setFirst()` method to set the first part of the pair. Then you could have:

```
Interval x = new ExtendedInterval();
Pair<Interval, Interval> pair = x.split(new Date());
pair.setFirst(new Interval());
```

That looks fine from the compiler's point of view, but it's unlikely that you should be able to call `setFirst(Interval)` on a `Pair<ExtendedInterval, ExtendedInterval>`.

Now all of this applied even if there *isn't* actually a `setFirst` method - because you can't tell the Java compiler that the `Pair<>` type itself is covariant; the generic variance is done at the *use* of the type.

Comment: That's a good solution.  The only downside I see is collecting the results from the call to super. `Pair<? extends Interval, ? extends Interval> baseInterval = super.split(dt);`

Comment: @Colin: Yes, that's a fair point... I'm not sure whether there's anything to be done about that, unfortunately :(